# D3 Tooltip for Chord Diagram Not Working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement a tooltip for each ribbon in my chord diagram that displays information about Eurovision voting relationships between countries to say:

> "(country) received (value) points from (country)"

which is shown in line 274 and I have tried doing this by writing the code in the last function below. There is currently a tooltip on the bottom screen displayed which says $100 but it is not displaying the information that I want. Here is my code:

```
                   <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <head>
                    <style>
                    body {
                      font: 10px sans-serif;
                      background-color: #F0F0F0;

                    }

                    h1 {
                      font-size: 400%;
                      position: fixed;
                      font-family: Helvetica;
                      top:500px;
                      left: 1100px;
                    }

                    h3 {
                      font-family: Helvetica;
                      position: fixed;
                      top:570px;
                      left: 1250px;
                    }

                    h4 {
                      position: absolute;
                      font-style: italic;
                      font-family: Helvetica;
                      top:800px;
                      left: 1170px;
                    }

                    svg {
                      position: fixed;
                    }

                    button {
                        background-color: #f44336; 
                        position: fixed;
                        border: none;
                        color: white;
                        padding: 15px 32px;
                        text-align: center;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        display: inline-block;
                        font-size: 16px;
                        margin: 4px 2px;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        top: 80px;
                        left: 10px;
                    }


                    .button2 {
                      background-color: #008CBA;
                      top:80px;
                      left: 120px;

                    } /* Blue */
                    .button3 {
                      background-color: #4CA350;
                      top:80px;
                      left: 230px;
                    } /* Red */ 

                    .group-tick line {
                      stroke: #000;
                    }

                    .ribbons {
                      fill-opacity: 1;

                    }

                    #tooltip.total {
                        position: absolute;
                        width: 200px;
                        height: auto;
                        padding: 10px;
                        background-color: white;
                        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                        border-radius: 10px;
                        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                        pointer-events: none;
                    }

                    #tooltip {
                        position: fixed;
                        font-family: Helvetica Neue;
                        font-size: 16px;
                        top:870px;
                        left:720px;
                        width: 200px;
                        height: auto;
                        padding: 10px;
                        background-color: white;
                        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                        border-radius: 10px;
                        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                        pointer-events: none;
                    }

                    #tooltip.hidden {
                        display: none;
                    }

                    #tooltip p {
                        margin: 0;
                        font-family: sans-serif;
                        font-size: 40px;
                        line-height: 20px;
                    }
                    </style>
                    <title>Julia Spyrou DECO3100 Assignment 3</title>
                    <body>
                    <h1>Voting at the Eurovision Song Contest</h1>
                    <h3>Mouseover individual chords to view voting relationships</h3>
                      <h4>NB: These visualisations exclude the countries that did not make the Final and their votes as well</h4>
                      <button class="button">2016</button>
                      <button class="button button2">2017</button>
                      <button class="button button3">2018</button>
                      <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
                        <p>$<span id="value">100</span></p>
                      </div>

                    <svg width="1050" height="1050"></svg>
                    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
                    <script>



                    var names = ["Ukraine","Spain","Slovenia","Lithuania","Austria","Estonia","Norway","Portugal","UK","Serbia","Germany","Albania","France","Czech Republic","Denmark","Australia","Finland","Bulgaria","Moldova","Sweden","Hungary","Israel","Netherlands","Ireland","Cyprus","Italy"];

                    var opacityDefault = 0.7;

                                var matrix = [
                                  [0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,4,12,0,0,0,1,15,0,0,7,0,0,2,8], //Ukraine
                                  [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,14,1,0,6,0,5,0,6,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,7,0], //Spain
                                  [5,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,8,0,0,2,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,1,0,0,0], //Slovenia
                                  [2,0,0,0,0,22,15,6,12,0,8,0,0,1,0,3,0,10,0,7,5,0,7,12,6,0],  //Lithuania
                                  [7,8,12,15,0,18,16,8,12,4,15,2,7,5,18,5,10,16,3,12,11,13,13,5,2,7], //Austria
                                  [4,3,5,12,2,0,0,19,6,3,2,4,7,5,7,8,12,2,13,0,0,8,4,7,5,10], //Estonia
                                  [0,3,5,0,0,6,0,0,5,9,0,0,0,0,8,1,0,0,7,10,7,0,4,0,5,12], //Norway
                                  [0,0,0,7,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,6,0,0], //Portugal
                                  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,3,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,10,0,6], //UK
                                  [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], //Serbia
                                  [0,13,4,7,16,6,18,8,3,10,0,14,8,3,24,12,1,6,8,6,1,8,24,16,3,13], //Germany
                                  [0,0,5,0,9,0,0,10,7,1,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,7,0,0,10,0,0,2,6,12], //Albania
                                  [19,10,2,15,0,0,8,5,0,0,0,12,0,0,2,0,9,5,0,5,0,6,0,4,4,0], //France
                                  [14,14,11,8,15,5,4,0,5,5,8,1,4,0,6,4,5,11,6,3,8,12,6,7,13,0], //Czech Republic
                                  [11,0,7,10,5,8,10,2,2,4,3,0,2,7,0,10,13,0,0,12,24,0,8,2,0,12], //Denmark
                                  [2,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,0,10,0,12,0,0,0,7,8,7,7,0,0,0,0], //Australia
                                  [0,0,0,0,0,12,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,3,0,4,0,0,0,9,0,6,0,0,0,0], //Finland
                                  [0,5,0,0,6,7,0,7,14,2,0,14,0,5,1,0,10,0,11,6,0,1,0,10,12,0], //Bulgaria
                                  [6,0,6,0,0,1,0,6,4,6,0,2,6,6,0,7,0,8,0,0,2,10,0,1,10,10], //Moldova
                                  [6,2,12,12,8,5,13,0,2,12,12,4,5,8,11,12,8,2,0,0,1,10,8,0,12,1], //Sweden
                                  [1,0,3,2,3,3,0,0,0,12,2,0,0,2,0,0,8,5,2,0,0,3,2,0,4,0], //Hungary
                                  [22,22,1,7,19,0,7,2,17,9,11,6,24,22,3,18,19,14,22,17,16,0,15,13,10,9], //Israel
                                  [8,0,7,3,1,1,9,0,0,7,5,0,6,0,5,0,2,0,0,1,8,0,0,3,0,0], //Netherlands
                                  [0,6,0,4,8,0,1,3,13,0,15,7,1,14,4,12,2,1,0,4,3,0,4,0,0,5], //Ireland
                                  [4,20,14,7,1,12,7,5,8,10,9,20,3,8,6,7,7,15,13,16,7,2,11,17,0,8], //Cyprus
                                  [5,10,10,7,10,7,0,14,0,14,12,24,10,2,0,0,10,6,8,0,6,5,7,0,15,0], //Italy

                                ];

                                var svg = d3.select("svg"),
                                    width = +svg.attr("width"),
                                    height = +svg.attr("height"),
                                    outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * 0.4 - 100,
                                    innerRadius = outerRadius - 20;

                                var formatValue = d3.formatPrefix(",.0", 1e3);

                                var chord = d3.chord()
                                    .padAngle(0.05)
                                    .sortSubgroups(d3.descending);

                                var arc = d3.arc()
                                    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                                    .outerRadius(outerRadius);

                                var ribbon = d3.ribbon()
                                    .radius(innerRadius);

                                var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                                    .domain(d3.range(4))
                                    .range(["#4B5320", "#50C878", "#98FB98", "#679267","#2E8B57","#043927", "#0B6623","#9DC183","#708238", "#C7EA46", "#3F704D","#00A86B","8F9779"]);

                                var g = svg.append("g")
                                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
                                    .datum(chord(matrix));

                          // Append the groups:
                                var group = g.append("g")
                                    .attr("class", "groups")
                                  .selectAll("g")
                                  .data(function(chords) { return chords.groups; })
                                  .enter().append("g");

                                group.append("path")
                                    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.index); })
                                    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(color(d.index)).darker(); })
                                    .attr("d", arc)
                                    .on("mouseover", highlightRibbons)
                                    .on("mouseout", showAllRibbons)

                          group.append("text")
                                  .each(function(d) { d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2; })
                                  .attr("dy", ".35em")
                                  .attr("class", "titles")
                                  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
                                  .attr("transform", function(d) {
                                    if (outerArcs = 0) {
                                      width = 10;
                                    }
                                    return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
                                    + "translate(" + (outerRadius + 10) + ")"
                                    + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
                                  })
                                  .text(function(d,i) { return names[i]; });  

                          // Append the ribbons
                                var ribbons = g.append("g")              // save the selection as a variable
                                    .attr("class", "ribbons")
                                  .selectAll("path")
                                  .data(function(chords) { return chords; })
                                  .enter().append("path")
                                    .attr("d", ribbon)
                                    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.target.index); })
                            .attr("class","ribbon")
                                    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(color(d.target.index)).darker(); })
                            .on("mouseover", highlightOneRibbon)
                            .on("mouseout",showAllRibbons);


                          // Highlight
                          function highlightRibbons(d,i) {
                            ribbons.filter(function(r) {
                                  if(!(r.target.index == i || r.source.index == i)) return r;
                                })
                                .transition()
                                .style("opacity",0.1)
                                .duration(500); 
                                ribbons.filter(function(r) {
                                if(r.target.index == i || r.source.index == i) return r;
                                })
                                .transition()
                                .style("opacity",1)
                                .duration(500);
                          }

                          // Unhighlight
                          function showAllRibbons() {
                            ribbons
                               //.transition()      // don't use for individual ribbons - transition is too long
                              .style("opacity",1)
                              //.duration(500);     // any visually effective transition will be too long given how quickly the mouse can cross multiple paths
                          }

                          // show a particular ribbon:
                          function highlightOneRibbon() {
                            ribbons.style("opacity",0.1);
                            d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
                              d3.select("#tooltip")
                              .style("left", xPosition + "100px")
                              .style("top", yPosition + "3000px")
                              .text(names[d.source.index] + " received " + d.source.value + " points from " + names[d.target.index]);

                          }

                          d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

                    </script>
```

If anyone can fix this that would be super! This may seem like a basic problem that can be rectified but I have never used D3 before and I apologise for asking so many questions on here. Unfortunately, I am running very low on time and sleep and have spent hours trying to resolve this issue. Cheers!